# How do I fix "wrong number of type arguments" while trying to implement a method?

Tags: methods, rust, implementation

I'm trying to implement a method:

```
struct Point<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

struct Line<T> {
    start: Point<T>,
    end: Point<T>,
}

impl Line {
    fn length(&self) -> f64 {
        let dx: f64 = self.start.x - self.end.x;
        let dy: f64 = self.start.y - self.end.y;
        (dx * dx + dy * dy).sqrt()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let point_start: Point<f64> = Point { x: 1.4, y: 1.24 };
    let point_end: Point<f64> = Point { x: 20.4, y: 30.64 };

    let line_a: Line<f64> = Line {
        start: point_start,
        end: point_end,
    };
    println!("length of line_a = {}", line_a.length());
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
  --> src/main.rs:11:6
   |
11 | impl Line {
   |      ^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a type parameter to the impl:

```
impl Line<f64> {
    fn length(&self) -> f64 {
        let dx: f64 = self.start.x - self.end.x;
        let dy: f64 = self.start.y - self.end.y;
        (dx * dx + dy * dy).sqrt()
    }
}
```

Comment: So This means that when I define a type, from that point on I have to type it whenever I use it.

Comment: @user3419211 Rust can infer the type in many situations, but for `impl` blocks and functions you need to specify it. That particular implementation of `length` depends on `self.start.x`/etc. being `f64`, so you have to tell Rust that it only works with those. You could however leave the type out from the variable declarations (use just `let dx = ...` instead `let dx:f64 = ...`) since it's already there in the `impl`.

Comment: @user3419211 Well, it doesn’t. You can write `impl<T> Line<T> { … }`. But the question is, how useful the functions _that_ generic (that actually do not depend on type `T`) can be. They can be, but clearly not in your particular case, since you need to know at least _something_ about `T` to perform calculations.